# Static Analysis raised 9 warning(s) that requires your attention. Click here to show the warning(s)

Tags: tokens, remix, solidity, warnings

I receive these warnings in REMIX so the question is:

Can I compile my contract and then verify it regardless of these warnings?

[image]

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.25;

library SafeMath {
  function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal constant returns (uint256) {
    uint256 c = a * b;
    assert(a == 0 || c / a == b);
    return c;
  }

  function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal constant returns (uint256) {
    assert(b > 0); // Solidity automatically throws when dividing by 0
    uint256 c = a / b;
    assert(a == b * c + a % b); // There is no case in which this doesn't hold
    return c;
  }

  function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal constant returns (uint256) {
    assert(b <= a);
    return a - b;
  }

  function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal constant returns (uint256) {
    uint256 c = a + b;
    assert(c >= a);
    return c;
  }
}

// ERC20 Token Smart Contract
contract Savingcoin {

    string public constant name = "Sapigcoin";
    string public constant symbol = "SAC";
    uint8 public constant decimals = 8;
    uint public _totalSupply = 150000000;
    uint256 public RATE = 300;
    bool public isMinting = true;
    string public constant generatedBy  = "Sapigcoin Devteam";

    using SafeMath for uint256;
    address public owner;

     // Functions with this modifier can only be executed by the owner
     modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
            _;
        }
         _;
     }

    // Balances for each account
    mapping(address => uint256) balances;
    // Owner of account approves the transfer of an amount to another account
    mapping(address => mapping(address=>uint256)) allowed;

    // Its a payable function works as a token factory.
    function () payable{
        createTokens();
    }

    // Constructor
    constructor() public {
        owner = 0x47281854d50bbfb81da704c267ab9693f1054f40; 
        balances[owner] = _totalSupply;
    }

    //allows owner to burn tokens that are not sold in a crowdsale
    function burnTokens(uint256 _value) onlyOwner {

         require(balances[msg.sender] >= _value && _value > 0 );
         _totalSupply = _totalSupply.sub(_value);
         balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value);

    }



    // This function creates Tokens  
     function createTokens() payable {
        if(isMinting == true){
            require(msg.value > 0);
            uint256  tokens = msg.value.div(100000000000000).mul(RATE);
            balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].add(tokens);
            _totalSupply = _totalSupply.add(tokens);
            owner.transfer(msg.value);
        }
        else{
            throw;
        }
    }


    function endCrowdsale() onlyOwner {
        isMinting = false;
    }

    function changeCrowdsaleRate(uint256 _value) onlyOwner {
        RATE = _value;
    }



    function totalSupply() constant returns(uint256){
        return _totalSupply;
    }
    // What is the balance of a particular account?
    function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns(uint256){
        return balances[_owner];
    }

     // Transfer the balance from owner's account to another account   
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value)  returns(bool) {
        require(balances[msg.sender] >= _value && _value > 0 );
        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value);
        balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
        Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

// Send _value amount of tokens from address _from to address _to
// The transferFrom method is used for a withdraw workflow, allowing contracts to send
// tokens on your behalf, for example to "deposit" to a contract address and/or to charge
// fees in sub-currencies; the command should fail unless the _from account has
// deliberately authorized the sender of the message via some mechanism; we propose
// these standardized APIs for approval:
function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value)  returns(bool) {
    require(allowed[_from][msg.sender] >= _value && balances[_from] >= _value && _value > 0);
    balances[_from] = balances[_from].sub(_value);
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
    allowed[_from][msg.sender] = allowed[_from][msg.sender].sub(_value);
    Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
    return true;
}

// Allow _spender to withdraw from your account, multiple times, up to the _value amount.
// If this function is called again it overwrites the current allowance with _value.
function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) returns(bool){
    allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value; 
    Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
    return true;
}

// Returns the amount which _spender is still allowed to withdraw from _owner
function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) constant returns(uint256){
    return allowed[_owner][_spender];
}

event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);
event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _value);
```

}

thansk in advance.

Comment: Please help to me please

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You should be able to run the smart contract since these are just warnings. Although they should be addressed at some point in the future. In addition, it would be helpful to post a link to the code rather than just an image.

Let me know if that helps!